# ProxyDroid for Linux

Tags: proxy, transparent-proxy

http://code.google.com/p/proxydroid/

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid

I need a similar app for ubuntu/linux which acts as a "global proxy" for every TCP connection. Is there anything already available?

Comment: If you're only concerned about TCP just add proxychains to your LD_PRELOAD on login. It doesn't address applications that clear environment variables though...